# How to maintain session in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on chrome extensions to logged in to application. so how to send request to the server to maintain session and cookies. Please suggest me if i am doing wrong?

Comment: When you issue an XMLHttpRequest from a Chrome extension, Chrome automatically includes the cookies for the target domain, so -- if you are already authenticated -- the request will execute as if you are authenticated.

Comment: Michael, would you please move your comment to an answer? It's not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to store you credentials on localStorage and each time the cookies/session expired to log in again with them.